# error installing pyper clip on mac os x 10.9.5

Tags: python, pip, pyperclip

I get the below error when trying to install pyperclip using `pip install pyperclip` on terminal

> dyld: Symbol not found: _fdopendir$INODE64   Referenced from:
>   /Users/*******/anaconda3/bin/python   Expected in:
>   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

I tried

```
pip3 install pyperclip
sudo pip3 install pyperclip
```

and got the same error every time

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: me too having issues with symbols not found. Yes, using conda virtual environments.